# enzyme simulate change event doesnt work over checkbox

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write a unit test over one of my react components. But my checkbox doesn't change after simulating change event over it.

My component:

```
const Checkbox = ({ label, onChange, id, isChecked }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="node" 
               id={"checkbox-" + id}
               onChange={onChange} 
               checked={isChecked}
               />
        <label className="treeview__level" htmlFor={"checkbox-" + id}>{label}</label>
      </>
    )
```

my test:

```
it('check if checkbox checked ', () => {
    const   testState = { isChecked: false },
            checkboxWrapper = shallow(
                <Checkbox   label= ""
                            id= "0"
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                testState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
                            }}
                            isChecked= {testState.isChecked}
                />
            ),
            input = checkboxWrapper.find('input').at(0);

        input.simulate('change', { target: { name: 'checked', value: true } });
        expect(input.props().checked).toBe(true);

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. At the moment the component is shallow rendered, the value of the `isChecked` props is `false`(the value of `testState.isChecked`) even though you simulate the `change` event. You just changed the value of `testState` property. The component does not re-render. That's why `input.props().checked` gives you a `false` value.

You may want to use [.setProps(nextProps[, callback]) => Self](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.md) to update the component's props.

E.g.
`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Checkbox = ({ label, onChange, id, isChecked }) => {
  console.log('isChecked:', isChecked);
  return (
    <>
      <input type="checkbox" name="node" id={'checkbox-' + id} onChange={onChange} checked={isChecked} />
      <label className="treeview__level" htmlFor={'checkbox-' + id}>
        {label}
      </label>
    </>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import { Checkbox } from './';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('60708551', () => {
  it('check if checkbox checked ', () => {
    const testState = { isChecked: false };
    const checkboxWrapper = shallow(
      <Checkbox
        label=""
        id="0"
        onChange={(e) => {
          testState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        }}
        isChecked={testState.isChecked}
      />,
    );
    const input = checkboxWrapper.find('input');
    input.simulate('change', { target: { name: 'isChecked', value: true } });
    expect(testState.isChecked).toBeTruthy();
    checkboxWrapper.setProps({ isChecked: testState.isChecked });
    expect(checkboxWrapper.find('input').props().checked).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60708551/index.test.tsx (13.81s)
  60708551
    ✓ check if checkbox checked  (43ms)

  console.log stackoverflow/60708551/index.tsx:4
    isChecked: false

  console.log stackoverflow/60708551/index.tsx:4
    isChecked: true

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.316s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60708551